Connection refused creating dataset in GCP bigquery with cloud.google.com/go/bigquery
My code have been working for a while but now I am having issues when accessing bigquery to create a dataset (I have checked it also get stuck when reading a table, for example). I am not having a *googleapi.Error but a *url.Error:

Being client a *"cloud.google.com/go/bigquery".Client created like the following:
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx,ProjectID)

And creating the dataset like this:
err := s.client.Dataset(datasetID).Create(ctx, &bigquery.DatasetMetadata{})

Then I am getting the previous url.Error in the picture. Till now all I got was nil or a expected *googleapi.Error with a status conflict code (meaning the dataset already exists).
To check auth I have run the following gcloud and bq commands:
$ gcloud auth list
   Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       ***@***.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`

$ bq ls --project_id develop-297605
I0812 09:11:12.917039 8395181056 bigquery_client.py:730] There is no apilog flag so non-critical logging is disabled.

Welcome to BigQuery! This script will walk you through the
process of initializing your .bigqueryrc configuration file.

First, we need to set up your credentials if they do not
already exist.

Setting project_id develop-297605 as the default.

BigQuery configuration complete! Type "bq" to get started.

          datasetId
 ----------------------------
  01GS*********

$ bq --location=EU mk --dataset ****05:testdataset
I0812 09:12:43.403765 8395181056 bigquery_client.py:730] There is no apilog flag so non-critical logging is disabled.
Dataset '****05:testdataset' successfully created.

After all of these, just in case I have run again login for application-default
$ gcloud auth application-default login

But everything remains the same.
Any help would be much appreciated.

misconfiguration between the IDE and the cli :( IDE was using proxy because of https_proxy env variable.
